# Whats the scala way to do this

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Trying to parse out a request.queryString which returns a Map[String, Seq[String]]

```
var route = ""
var queryString = "?"
for((k,v) <- request.queryString) {
  if(k == "route"){ route = v.head }
  else {
    queryString += k +"="+ v.head +"&"
  }
}
queryString = queryString.substring(0, queryString.length() -1 );
```

This works fine but is very imperative.  I'm sure there is a more functional way to do this.  Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Help is here! With excessive commenting.

```
val RouteKey = "route"

val route = request
    .getOrElse(RouteKey, Nil) // will return the route, or empty list
    .headOption               // either Some[head] or None
    .getOrElse("")            // if None, empty string

val queryString = (request - RouteKey)     // remove the route from the request
  .map { case (k, v) =>                    // map each key/value pair
    k + "=" + v.headOption.getOrElse("") } // into key=value strings
  .mkString("?", "&", "")                  // make that list into a single string
```

You'll notice that I used the same pattern to safely get the `head` from a list, to handle empty lists.  If you find yourself doing that a lot, then you can just add that method to `Seq[String]`.

```
implicit def pimpedStringSeq(seq: Seq[String]) = new {
  def headStr = seq.headOption.getOrElse("")
}

val RouteKey = "route"

val route = request.getOrElse(RouteKey, Nil).headStr

val queryString = (request - RouteKey).map { case (k, v) => k + "=" + v.headStr }
  .mkString("?", "&", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Not so much better, but you could use a fold.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

request.queryString.foldLeft(("?", "")) { case ((route, queryString), (k, v)) =>
  if(k == "route")
    (v.head, queryString)
  else
    (route, queryString + k + "=" + v.head + "&")
} :-> (_.init)
```

That cute smile operator (`:->`) is used for transforming the second element of the 2-tuple that we get at the end of the fold. It can be read as follows:

```
t :-> f == (t._1, f(t._2))
```

You can see the source [here](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/MAB.scala#L9).

Example from console:

```
scala> val requestQueryString = Map("route" -> Seq("a"), "foo" -> Seq("b"), "bar" -> Seq("c"))
requestQueryString: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Seq[java.lang.String]] = Map(route -> List(a), foo -
> List(b), bar -> List(c))

scala> var route = ""
var queryString = "?"
for((k,v) <- requestQueryString) {
  if(k == "route"){ route = v.head }
  else {
    queryString += k +"="+ v.head +"&"
  }
}
queryString = queryString.substring(0, queryString.length() -1 );
route: java.lang.String = a
queryString: java.lang.String = ?foo=b&bar=c
queryString: java.lang.String = ?foo=b&bar=c

scala> requestQueryString.foldLeft(("?", "")) { case ((queryString, route), (k, v)) =>
  if(k == "route")
    (queryString, v.head)
  else
    (queryString + k + "=" + v.head + "&", route)
}
res8: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) = (?foo=b&bar=c&,a)

scala> ((_: String).init) <-: res8
res9: (String, java.lang.String) = (?foo=b&bar=c,a)

scala> requestQueryString.foldLeft(("?", "")) { case ((route, queryString), (k, v)) =>
  if(k == "route")
    (v.head, queryString)
  else
    (route, queryString + k + "=" + v.head + "&")
} :-> (_.init)
res10: (java.lang.String, String) = (a,foo=b&bar=c)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `:->` in scalaz?

Comment: Whatever the purpose is, the operator makes me smile :->

Comment: @om-nom-nom, I expanded my answer.